# Dynamic Django-Javascript [Beginner]

Tags: javascript, python, django, dynamic, view

This is what I am trying to accomplish for my project.

Context: Education math site

Goal: When the user clicks on the "Beginners" section, he will be asked a question. The question will be processed and if it is corrcet he can press "Again" and then, another random question is asked.

Each question is dynamically generated, it is stored in a view NOT a model/database.

Thus I have one .html file which renders multiple views that are randomly selected (i.e. the questiosn are randomly selected to be displayed).

Each question is different.

Sample question "Mary has 8 apples, she eats 3. How much does she have left?"

In this question, I want to make JavaScript print out 8 pictures of apples.

Another question "Bob has 6 cars and buys 4 more..."

In this question, I want to make JavaScript print out 4 cars

etc, etc...

**Is it ok to have one javascript file which detects the type of question answered and generates the appropriate graphcis, or would that be bad practice as the file could get really big really fast and I'm concerned it might slow down the server. IS there a better way of doing this**

*Can I send the javascript code to the .js file from the Django view, so that way only the relevant code needs to be processed*?

I already know how to make JavaScript do what I want it to do, I'm just not sure that it's the most efficient / optimised way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

- You store all your data in the HTML and you first hide it, then display it on demand with Javascript. This will result it super big (and probably messy HTML and JS) files. But this could do what you want. You can do your project simply with a HTML/CSS/JS stack.
- You create a pretty empty HTML file that you will dynamically modify using AJAX calls to a Django view. This time it is the Django Ajax View logic that will become messy depending on how many questions you have.

> as the file could get really big really fast and I'm concerned it might slow down the server

Page loading will only get longer depending on the amount of images and Javascript to load.

> Can I send the javascript code to the .js file from the Django view, so that way only the relevant code needs to be processed?

Ultimately you can send javascript from Django to the frontend, but it is not so wise to do so. You should rather optimize your Javascript to focus on reusability.

> I'm just not sure that it's the most efficient / optimised way

Most efficient / optimized way would be with a database and Ajax to query the questions randomly. I mean, you would be able to do much more with a technology meant to store data.

And just as I was finishing this post, I was wondering why you wouldn't want to use a Database.
I thought maybe you could not setup a database server, that's fine, you can use [SQLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases). It is [serverless](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html), and it would ease your project so much in my opinion. Mind my assumption if I guessed wrong.

Comment: I was thinking similar to #1, except each view would pass a parameter like "Question 3" that is rendered on the HTML page but hidden. There'd be a javscript/jquery function that grabs the node (eg with class="hidden") and render dynamic images / animations based on that question (eg if p = 'question 3').  Howevcer the images/animations would be stored externally so they wouldn't have to load on the page and it would be easier to maintain. 

Oh reason I don't store questions in database is because the questions are dynamically generated -- well, the value of the numbers used in them.

Comment: You can do all the dynamic things you want with Ajax. 
Generate the numbers in the backend, send this kind of JSON to the frontend : 
`{"question": "Mary has 8 apples, she eats 3. How much does she have left?", "numbers": [8, 3], "operation": "substract"}`

Your frontend will only display the question, but your Javascript will store all the rest and send it back to the Django backend, something like :
`{"numbers": [8, 3], "operation": "substract", "answer": 5}`

After this, it all comes down to where you want to store the results. 
Javascript or Django. If Django, you need SQLite.

Comment: I tried doing something like that but ran into some difficulties with AJAX / Django together, so I used sessions to store answers and view functions to process them. It ended up working that way. I will try and do it your way for more practice

Comment: If it does what you want, it is at least good enough.
I would suggest you give another try to AJAX, there are some good resources to get you started:
[here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)
or
[there](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)

Comment: Thanks will look into them. I also just had another idea, using a custom .js file for each question, and passing the name of the js script with each Django view to the script src attribute tag